# AWS healthd daemon warning - nginx log file does not exists

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a nodejs app using elasticbeanstalk with nginx.

When I check the log directory /var/log/nginx/

1. healthd folder exists and
2. nginx is creating /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2019-10-04-13

But in /var/log/healthd folder there is a daemon.log file in which I am getting below error after every 5 seconds.

```
    # Logfile created on 2019-10-04 13:46:46 +0000 by logger.rb/47272
A, [2019-10-04T13:46:46.849261 #8094]   ANY -- : healthd daemon 1.0.3 initialized
W, [2019-10-04T13:46:47.011762 #8094]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2019-10-04-13" does not exist
W, [2019-10-04T13:46:52.012037 #8094]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2019-10-04-13" does not exist
W, [2019-10-04T13:46:57.012270 #8094]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2019-10-04-13" does not exist
W, [2019-10-04T13:47:02.012593 #8094]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2019-10-04-13" does not exist
W, [2019-10-04T13:47:07.012811 #8094]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2019-10-04-13" does not exist
W, [2019-10-04T13:47:12.013037 #8094]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2019-10-04-13" does not exist
W, [2019-10-04T13:47:17.013245 #8094]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2019-10-04-13" does not exist
W, [2019-10-04T13:47:22.013467 #8094]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2019-10-04-13" does not exist
W, [2019-10-04T13:47:27.013679 #8094]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2019-10-04-13" does not exist
W, [2019-10-04T13:47:32.013903 #8094]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2019-10-04-13" does not exist
```

So how to make daemon read nginx healthd log files?

Comment: Hi, we're you able to find a fix? This is my issue now too

Comment: no haven't figure out yet

Comment: Same. This is a head scratcher...

Comment: Same problem here. I've tried adding the script that's linked below but now can't even get the app to deploy with the script.

Comment: Have you changed the timezone?

Comment: @dannyshaw timezone is UTC so doesnt look like its related to this

Answer (score 2):

I too encountered this mysterious error. Made especially cryptic by the fact that if you check, you'll find /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.XXX does exist!

What I discovered is that under some circumstances, healthd requires additional configuration to resolve this error.

Take a look at this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-serverlogs.html

Once I provided healthd with the proper log formation configuration, this error went away.

Comment: I have been trying to solve this; can you please provide your config details? Some thing is off on my end; THANKS